# Django template translation - Is it possible to use object attributes

Tags: django, internationalization

Django's [`{% blocktrans %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag) template tag doesn't support object attribute accesses, nor template filters. Is there any django library that will allow me to use object attributes and filters inside a blocktrans-type-tag?

Essentially I want to be able to write:

```
{% load ??? %}
{% blocktrans %}The price is €{{ object.price }}.{% endblocktrans %}
```

I know the standard Django advice is to use variables on the `blocktrans`, but I want to avoid that. It results in a much larger template and involves much more typing and template rewriting in order to i18n-ify your django app.

Before I go and write this library myself, I want to see if anyone has done it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`{% with %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#with):

```
{% with object.price as myprice %}
{% blocktrans %}The price is € {{ myprice }}.{% endblocktrans %}
```